# Finding the range of (complex) roots of a cubic

Tags: complex-numbers, cubics

I'm trying to show that all roots of $a+bz+cz^2+z^3=0$ lie inside the circle
$$ |z|=\max\{1, |a|+|b|+|c|\}. $$
The progress I've reached so far is merely
$$ |z|=r;\quad 0\le |a|+|b|r+|c|r^2+r^3. $$
I don't understand where the "$1$" comes from and how I can derive $|a|+|b|+|c|$ from the equation.

Update: I got this
$$ r^3\le |a|+|b|r+|c|r^2. $$

and it is clear where $1$ comes from. But the case when $r>1$ is still not very clear to me.

Comment: This is Lagrange's bound on the roots of a polynomial.  The proof can be found online in many places, including Wikipedia.

Comment: oof I don't know that lol
thanks!

Comment: As mentioned by Andy Walls, this result is well-known and you can find the proof [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrical_properties_of_polynomial_roots#Lagrange%27s_and_Cauchy%27s_bounds). Btw, you were very close to the proof. If $r\leq 1$, then the unit ball works. If not, then $r\gt 1$ and thus $r^3\leq |a|+|b|r+|c|r^2\leq |a|r^2+|b|r^2+|c|r^2$ and the proof follows by dividing both sides of the inequality by $r^2$